# Enunciate Documentation Modify or Remove "Generated by" Sentence?

Tags: documentation, enunciate

When I generate docs using Enunciate at every page it rights that:

```
Generated by Enunciate.
```

Can I modify that string or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

See [Applying a Custom Skin to Enunciate Documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Applying+a+Custom+Skin+to+Enunciate%27s+Documentation).

Comment: Since Enunciate move to github, the correct Link is: https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Custom-Skin